# ggplot mapping aes error when I add anything

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I plot barplot like this:

```
p<- ggplot(corttestunitedcol, aes(x=Sex, y=mean, fill=Treatment_Status)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))
```

beautiful. What I want.

However, if I add anything to this, it get

> Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`

For example adding titles:

```
p<- ggplot(corttestunitedcol, aes(x=Sex, y=mean, fill=Treatment_Status)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge(),
           labs(title = "Corticosterone",
                y = "mean plasma Corticosterone (pg/ml)", x = "")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))
```

Or

```
p<- ggplot(corttestunitedcol, aes(x=Sex, y=mean, fill=Treatment_Status)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge(),
          facet_wrap(~Sex)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9))
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: don't put it into `geom_*` function, just add after all geoms `+ facet_wrap(~Sex)`

Comment: What @inscaven said is also valid for the `labs` in the *"For example adding titles:"* code.

Comment: thank you @inscaven ! That was it!

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if you've shared the whole code with all the necessary variables to execute it, then we could reproduce your results.

Anyway, I think you're adding **ggplot** functions in the wrong way.
`labs()` and `facet_wrap()` are functions just like `geom_bar()` and `geom_errorbar()`. Therefore, you should also add them, instead of throwing them into `geom_bar()`.

I think the following code chunk would solve your problem:

```
p <- ggplot(corttestunitedcol, aes(x = Sex, y = mean, fill = Treatment_Status)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', colour = 'black',
           position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd),
                width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ Sex) +
  labs(title = 'Corticosterone',
       x = '', y = 'mean plasma Corticosterone (pg/ml)')
```

Let us know if your problem was solved.